# ssh Lockup With ForwardX11=yes

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

Why do both of these lockup, never giving me my prompt back?

```
% ssh -X $(hostname) exit
% ssh -o ForwardX11=yes $(hostname) exit
```

They both create an *ssh* session on the current machine with X11 forwarding.  Yeah, I know it's weird.  Interestingly, changing the `exit` to `ls` also locks up, but gives me a file listing first.  That implies the lockup is somehow tied to terminating the shell or session, but I'm just guessing.  Also, the lockup goes away if I remove the `-X` or the `-o ForwardX11=yes`.  My *~/.ssh/config* is empty.  In case it helps, here are some selected lines from running with `-vvv`, including when I Ctrl-C at the end.

```
% ssh -Xvvv $(hostname) exit
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
...
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
...
debug1: Host 'my-host-name' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:275
...
debug3: input_userauth_banner
<I see my message of the day here>
...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec  #without -X, this becomes pledge: network
...
debug1: Sending environment.
...
debug1: Sending command: exit
...
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
...
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
...
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
...
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)
  #1 x11 (t4 r3 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 7/7/-1 sock 7 cc -1)
  #2 x11 (t4 r4 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 8/8/-1 sock 8 cc -1)

^Cdebug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #1 x11 (t4 r3 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 7/7/-1 sock 7 cc -1)
  #2 x11 (t4 r4 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 8/8/-1 sock 8 cc -1)

debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 x11 (t4 r4 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 8/8/-1 sock 8 cc -1)

debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 2.
```

Comment: SSH multiplexes multiple data channels, one of which may still be in use. You can check the diagnostic output by adding `-v` to the command line. Add it multiple times to increase verbosity.

Comment: Does your .bashrc (or similar file) on the remote system launch any processes in the background?

Comment: Longshot: What happens if you add `sudo` before your command?

Comment: @Kenster, I do fork a few processes in my _.bashrc_, but only in the foreground.  Without the `-X`, it works.  Also, changing `exit` to `ls` gives me output before locking up.  So I don't think any of those are hanging.  My _.bash_logout_ is empty.

Comment: @Zeth, I don't have _sudo_ access, unfortunately.

Comment: I modified my question to clarify that the lockup happens only with `-X` or `-o ForwardX11=yes`.  I also added output from running with `-vvv`.

Comment: I'm just guessing at the meaning of the verbose output, but the last few lines imply there are three channels, 1 and 2 are closed, but 0 is still open.  I'm not sure what to do with that.  Does anyone else see the lockup?

Comment: I think it’s the other way around. Channel 0 (tty) is gone, channels 1 and 2 remain active. Which again begs the question: What is it that used X11 forwarding? You should try to find out. Maybe also start with `-N` (no remote command, meaning no shell) to see what happens then.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense about the channels.  I still get a lockup with `-N`, and the verbose output is the same until the `pledge: exec` line.  After that, there are just a few more lines, none interesting or appearing to be related to open sockets.  I do run _xauth_ in my _~/.bashrc_, but in the foreground.  The fact that I get output from the `ls` says that doesn't hang.